# Форматы numpy.loadtxt для Python

Tags: python

Какие форматы кушает `numpy.loadtxt`? Я знаю про `txt`, `prn`, какие еще?
Где это можно посмотреть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.loadtxt` кушает текстовый формат, а кем он написан и какое расширение неважно. Если файл отвечает определенным правилам, он будет открываться. А если формат не кушается можно использовать дополнительные опции для пропуска комментариев или заголовков, установки разделителя и т.п. Можно указать свои типы при преобразовании.

А посмотреть про то как работает `loadtxt` можно вот тут [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).